# How correctly add RetryAdvice to Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm very new to Spring Integration DSL and I need to add retrial with recovery to the existing IntegrationFlow. It takes data from Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter and send it through different channels. I want to add RequestHandlerRetryAdvice for the whole flow.

My idea was to add it to the adapter, but it seems to support only ErrorChannel, without Advices & Retries and such. I've ended up wrapping the whole flow after Jms.messageDriverChannelAdapter in a .gateway with advice and .requireReply(false). It feels like a hack, but I couldn't find a better way to do it. Is there any better way to deal with such situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Spring AMQP's listener container a JMS one doesn't provide a hook to inject `Advice` chain into it, so, we really don't have choice and workaround it somehow. The `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` and a `.gateway()` DSL is not so bad idea to go. The point is that a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` is applied only for the particular `handleRequestMessage()` method and is not propagated downstream. Having the flow wrapped into the gateway call from the mentioned `handleRequestMessage()` is the way to go.

I think we can come up with the solution on the `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint` to wrap an internal listener with injected `Advice` chain, where one of them might be a `RetryOperationsInterceptor`.

Please, raise a GH issue and we'll think what we can do.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'll do as you suggested. If you don't mind, could you please explain how .replyRequired and .replyTimeout should be used in this case? What will happen on timeout - will the gateway just stop executing? Does .replyRequired affect its behavior, like by treating timeout as a normal outcome?